# How to inherit Injected service from superclass into subclassed component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, inheritance, typescript, dependency-injection

As of Angular v2.0, [inheritance is supported between components](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f5c8e0989d85bc064f689fc3595207dfb29413f4).

Given a parent class, with a service provided to the constructor via dependency-injection, is it possible to define a child class which **extends** (or inherits)  its parent class, such that it can access the parent's *service*?

```
import {MyService} from './my.service'
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
   selector: 'parent-selector',
   providers: [MyService],
   templateUrl: 'my_template.html'
})
export class ParentClass implements OnInit{
    public foobar: number;
    constructor(protected _my_service: MyService){};

    ngOnInit(){
        foobar = 101;
    }
}

@Component({
   selector: 'child-selector',
   templateUrl: 'my_template.html'
})
export class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    public new_child_function(){
        // This prints successfully
        console.log(this.foobar);
        // This throws an error saying my_service is "undefined"
        this._my_service.service_function();
    }
}
```

When we try and call `new_child_function()` from the child class, it succesfully accesses its parent's member **foobar**, but the call to `this._my_service.service_function()` gives us the following not-so-fun error:

```
Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

It appears the parent-injected service *is not* available to the child in this specific case. I am wondering:

1. Is this a current *known* limitation of Angular2's Component Inheritance support?
2. Is there something missing/wrong with this code sample?
3. Is this a bug with Angular2's support for Component Inheritance?

Comment: why are you using inheritance in your components?

Comment: I misread your question. This is not parent and child but sub and superclass.

Comment: @Gunter can you clarify? In my experience, parent is to child as  superclass is to subclass (when the relationship tree is 2-deep). Am I missing something?

Comment: A parent component is hosting the child component in it's view. A subclass extends a superclass and inherits it's implementation. These two are entirely different concepts.

Comment: You are correct. An Angular2 child component can be nested within an Angular2 parent component, in a "parent-child" component relationship. The relationship in this post refers to a general (non-Angular) inheritance pattern between a Parent & Child class. (Also referred to as "Super and Subclass".) I have updated the question title to avoid confusion.

Comment: In TypeScript, `ChildClass` has to explicitly call `ParentClass`' constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Make it `public` or `protected`, i.e.

```
constructor(protected _my_service: MyService){};
```

> if you do not use in the constructor `protected`, `private`, or `public`, for example, DI, the range of the variable `_my_service` is the scope of the `constructor { }` you could not use from another function.

---

You can read more about [Parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) and how they are declared and accessed.

> Parameter properties are declared by prefixing a constructor parameter with an *accessibility modifier* or `readonly`, or both.

Comment: probably `protected` would be better

Comment: This is not a valid answer. Typescript's constructor parameters default to ``public``, so while it may be better for the service to be ``protected``, the example above has a public service. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers

Comment: this is a constructor variable @TheAelfinn

Comment: I believe constructor variables are also, by default, public. Can you dig up any documentation on the topic? Nevertheless, I tried explicitly making the service parameter public, and it did not have an effect.

Comment: @TheAelfinn constructor parameters will create and initialize a member of a class only if they have an accessibility modifier. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties

Comment: +1 for the doc, but this still doesn't resolve the issue. The code above still fails despite the ``protected`` accessibility modifier on the service.

Comment: If it fails inside a service then you have other errors.

Comment: I think from the example given by the question, it fails inside a component dependency injection.